# copy char before /after special operator in c

Tags: c, string

I have a value in the format of "xxx/yyy" , i used following method to extract the two values before and after "/"

```
            char * ptr = "xxx/yyy";  

            part2 = strchr( ptr, '/');
            if ( part2 != NULL)
               part2++;

            part1 = strtok(ptr,"/");
```

Result: part1 = xxx
        part2 = yyy

This works fine, but when i have the value of ptr like "/yyy" , my result is

```
       ***part1 = yyy !!!!!! IT should be an empty char!!!!***
       part2 = yyy
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: your code will not work in the first case as strtok replaces the token char with a '\0', thus making strchr to return null.

Comment: `strtok` should not be used on a string literal that modifies the string.

Answer (score 0):

The strtok function skips all characters that you pass in the second string. Therefore you get  the first string that does not include these characters for the first call. When you need a different behavior you should consider implementing `my_strtok()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
void main(void)
{
char *a=malloc(strlen(ptr)/2);
char *b=malloc(strlen(ptr)/2);
int i=0;j=0,w;
while(*(ptr+i)!='/') {
*(a+j)=*(ptr+i);
j++; i++;
}
*(a+j)='\0';
j=0;
for(w=i+1;w<=strlen(ptr);w++) {
*(b+j)=*(ptr+w);
j++;
}
printf("pure string : %s \ntoken1 : %s \ntoken2= %s", ptr, a, b);
free(a);
free(b);
}
```

Comment: Good idea, bad implementation. Please compile and test your code before posting it here. You should allocate memory according to the required string lengths as chars; what you do is allocate space to hold a pointer. You don't null-terminate the first string `a`. You also don't treat the case where there is no slash; you should also check for `'\0'` in your first loop. Also, because this is a self-contained program, you should `free` the two allocated strings.

Comment: It's supposed to be a point/idea not a ready to use code.however I will fix it.

Comment: Looks like C code to me with proper includes and a full `main`, so it should compile. If you want to illustrate an idea, please use pseudocode, i.e. a simplified representation of the idea where it is clear at first glance that it is not real code.

Answer (score 0):

Harper has already given you the explanation for the behaviour you observe with `strtok`. Luckily, you have already done the work that `strtok` would do in your case: You have found the location of the slash. If there's a slash, you could do what `strtok` would do: Terminate the first string with a zero by overwriting the slash:

```
int main()
{
    char ptr[] = "xxx/yyy";  
    char *part1, *part2;

    part1 = ptr;
    part2 = strchr(ptr, '/');
    if (part2 != NULL) *part2++ = '\0';

    printf("'%s', '%s'\n", part1, part2);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the input string must be modifiable, which your string literal is not. (It happens to be modifiable on your platform, but you should not rely on it; use a char array `ptr[]` instead of a pointer to a string literal, `*ptr`.)